# what causes the difference between code and fnc in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

according to MDN

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);
```

as you can see:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
            alert(2);
        }, 0);
        alert(1);
```

the result is fristly '1' and then '2'.

```
   setTimeout(alert(2), 0);
   alert(1);
```

however,the result is fristly '2' and then '1'.

what causes the difference?

Comment: in the second case `alert` is executed immediately and no timeout is being set.

Comment: The JS is resolving ```alert(2)```, as it may return a function which you intend to timeout. The first is a legitimate timeout, which will run after the current execution queue.

Comment: BTW there's one more option for you to try: `setTimeout("alert(2)", 0);`

Comment: By "code" they mean a code string, i.e. `"alert(2)"`. What you were passing is just the result of calling `alert` immediately.

Comment: Does you mean that as long as the code is not  a code string, it will be executed firstly regardless of ` delay `

Answer (score 1):

In the case of

```
setTimeout(alert(2), 0);
alert(1);
```

First `alert(2)` is executed and its return value (i.e. `undefined`) is passed to `setTimeout` function, while in the first example a function is passed to the `setTimeout` function.

Also have a look at: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)